# how to use ComparisonPredicate as part of query in a procedure using oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am writing a query where I am checking for column value based on the values like Equals,Not Equals and Starts With.I want to pass these values to query dynamically. can any one suggest me.

```
SELECT * FROM EMP E WHERE E.SAL >= 30000
```

I should be able to pass >=,=<,like operators dynamically in procedure. please suggest me design.

UPDATE

THis is what I am looking for

```
SELECT e.ename,e.empno,e.job,e.sal,d.deptno
FROM   DEPT D,emp  e
WHERE  d.deptno = e.deptno
AND CASE
WHEN e.deptno = 10
AND  e.sal >= 1000 and e.name like('%j')
-- THEN e.name like('%j')
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END = 1;
```

I miss understood the THEN. we can have only expression as part of it.

thank you every one.

Comment: Sorry, but your edit just made it more confusing. Do you want to have different operators in the `THEN e.name like('%j'%)` bit, or are you having problems getting the CASE to work (which, as you can see, doesn't work like that)?

Comment: To use a CASE *within* SQL, it has to be an **expression**, i.e. returns a value - you can "return a predicate" like you are doing. For example: `WHERE e.name LIKE CASE WHEN e.deptno=10 AND e.sal>=1000 THEN '%j' ELSE '%' END`

Comment: actually i am having oracle type as input. in that i will pass key and value. since it is object type i will pass multiple keys and values for particular user. it is working fine. Now user can have options to choose the value as =,>=,<=,like for value. My challenge is stuck here. I have to pass operator dynamically in between AND PRTKEY.PRTY_TYP_VAL =(>=)(<=)(Like) ITTPKTYP.PARTY_KEY_VALUE i have to compare Object type with orginal table .It is tough to post the code here since it has more than 200 lines.

Comment: You have two choices: dynamic SQL or static SQL. If it's fairly simple, you can use simple SQL as in my answer. If it's fairly complex, you may need to use dynamic SQL. Look up `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't discount the simple approach:

```
CASE in_comparison_operator
WHEN '>=' THEN
  SELECT * INTO ... FROM EMP E WHERE E.SAL >= 30000;
WHEN '<=' THEN
  SELECT * INTO ... FROM EMP E WHERE E.SAL <= 30000;
WHEN 'LIKE' THEN
  SELECT * INTO ... FROM EMP E WHERE E.ENAME like ('J%');
END;
```

Comment: I think you understood it wrong. as part of sql query in where clause i need to check for this. i have edited my post.based on the input i have to add that operator. for example user chooses equal i have place query like emp.sal=1000 or emp.sal>1000.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to write some dynamic stored procedure, based of if else condition.
Below is an idea, rest you can implement your login here

```
create procedure DynamicQuery
@ColumnName varchar(20),
@Operator varchar(10),
@Value varchar(10)
as

declare @qry nvarchar(max)
set @qry = 'select * from Emp e where ' + @ColumnName + ' '
if(@Operator = 'like')
begin
set @qry = @qry + ' like (''' + @Value + ''')'
end

else
begin
set @qry = @qry + ' ' + @Operator + ' '  + @Value 
end
print @qry

exec sp_executesql @qry
```

Comment: thank you. what u are saying is compare operator and place the equery in if else condition. here i have to validate against these many values EQ - Equals,NE - Not Equals,LT - Less Than, LE - Less Than or Equal To, GT - Greater Than,GE - Greater Than or Equal To. for all these i have to write if else or case condition.

Comment: no not really....see these comparison operator except like and in, has some different formats to write, where as <= >= <> they are just like operator then value....so you have to write if condition for like and in operator hopefully.

Comment: That's not valid Oracle PL/SQL

Comment: AND PRTKEY.PRTY_TYP_VAL + V_EQUAL_OPERATOR + ITTPKTYP.PARTY_KEY_VALUE it says invalid relational operator.